# A program that contains employee data if employee tenure is more than three years call all functions in main (In java)

Tags: java

I am writing a program in java that contains variables to hold employee data like

- `EmployeeCode`
- `EmployeeName`
- `EmployeeDateOfJoining`

I have written a function that assigns user defined values to these variables that I mentioned above. In variable `EmployeeDateOfJoining` i store values like `3-3-2019`. After this, I want to write another function that asks the user to enter the current date and then checks if the employee tenure is more than three years or not.
 If an employee's tenure is more than 3 years than call the functions otherwise not.

```
package assignment;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Calendar;
public class EmployeeData {

    String EmployeeName, EmployeeCode, DateOfJoining;
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    Calendar c1=Calendar.getInstance();
    public void Employee_Data()
    {
    System.out.println("Enter the employee name:");
    EmployeeName=input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter Employee code:");
    EmployeeCode=input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Current date:"+(c1.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"-" 
    +c1.get(Calendar.DATE)+ "-" +c1.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    }
    public void checkdate()
    {
    System.out.print("Enter his date of joining --> - should be used and all entries must be integer:");
    DateOfJoining=input.nextLine();

    }
}
```

**This is main Class**

```
package assignment;

public class Assignment {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EmployeeData E1=new EmployeeData();
        E1.Employee_Data();
        E1.checkdate();
    }
    }
```

If i enter date like `21-3-2019` then it should subtract this from current date and should show me output in this format e.g `22-3-2018`

Comment: I would advise you not to do I/Os in a business class, and definitely not in a constructor.

Comment: Also, try to stick to `camelCase` convention in Java

Comment: I don't think this is the actual code you would deploy in production, because it is not good way to write Logic in this way. To perform operation on date you can follow this link https://www.baeldung.com/java-date-difference

Comment: You haven't asked a question so this looks more like a do-my-homework-for-me request. Please prove me wrong by improving your post.

Comment: How can i improve my post plz brief me

Comment: The actual statement is this Write a program  that contains variables to hold employee data like; employeeCode, employeeCode, and dateOfJoining. Write a function that assigns the user defined values to these variables. Write another function that asks the user to enter current date and then checks if the employee tenure is more than three years or not. Call the function in main.

Comment: Now write another runner class that declares two employee objects and checks their tenure periods.